# creating business network in composer to fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

If we can build a business network in composer playground online(or) locally and then deploy  network in fabric, make a  REST call from an angular app (user facing) to connect to blockchain.

Do I still need to learn about the fabric implementation or its infrastructure, When composer has provided me with necessary toolings to work with blockchain.

What am I missing in this ?

ps:I am still in the early phase of learning hyperledger and so not very clear as to use which and when.

Answer (score 0):

Composer just provide necessary tools to work with blockchain.

But if you want to build your own blockchain network, You need to learn about fabric.

In composer guide, it mainly showed two fabric networks: One organization Hyperledger Fabric and Two organizations Hyperledger Fabric.

Let's say if you want to add one more organization or add one more peer node for each organization. You can't implement the requirements just utilize composer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also quite new to this. So if I understand well your answer lissdy, if I follow the developer tutorial (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) my network will be deployed  but with only one peer ? And I need to use fabric to go further ?